# Different interpretations of height of a binary tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree, terminology

I am studying data structures and algorithms and this thing is really confusing me

Height of a binary tree, as it is also used in AVL search tree.

According to the book I am following "DATA STRUCTURES by Lipschutz" , it says "the depth (or height) of a tree T is the maximum number of nodes in a branch of T. This turns out to be 1 more than the largest level number of T. The tree 7 in figure 7.1 has depth 5."

figure 7.1 :

```
             A 
            / \
           /   \           
          /     \
         /       \
        B         C
       / \       / \
      D   E     G   H
         /         / \
        F         J   K
                 /
                L
```

But, on several other resources, height has been calculated differently, though same definition is given. For example as I was reading from internet http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/djimenez/utsa/cs3343/lecture5.html

" Here is a sample binary tree:

```
                   1
                  / \
                 /   \
                /     \
               /       \
              2         3
             / \       / \
            /   \     /   \
           /     \   /     \
          6       7 4       5
         / \     /         /
        9  10   11        8
```

The height of a tree is the maximum of the depths of all the nodes. So the tree above is of height 3. "

Another source http://www.comp.dit.ie/rlawlor/Alg_DS/searching/3.%20%20Binary%20Search%20Tree%20-%20Height.pdf

says, "Height of a Binary Tree
For a tree with just one node, the root node, the height is defined to be 0, if there are 2
levels of nodes the height is 1 and so on. A null tree (no nodes except the null node)
is defined to have a height of –1. "

Now these last 2 explanations comply with each other but not with the example given in the book.

Another source says "There are two conventions to define height of Binary Tree
1) Number of nodes on longest path from root to the deepest node.
2) Number of edges on longest path from root to the deepest node.

In this post, the first convention is followed. For example, height of the below tree is 3.

```
              1
             / \
            2   3
           / \
          4   5
```

"
In this, I want to ask how can the number of nodes and edges between root and leaf be the same ?
And what will be the height of a leaf node, according to the book it should be 1 (as the number of largest level is 0, so height should be 0+1=1,
but it is usually said height of leaf node is 0.
Also why does the book mention depth and height as the same thing?
This thing is really really confusing me, I have tried clarifying from a number of sources but cant seem to choose between the two interpretations. 
Please help.

==> I would like to add to it since now I am accepting the conventions of the book,
   in the topic of AVL search trees where we need to calculate the BALANCE FACTOR (which is the difference of the heights left and right subtrees)
it says :

```
            C (-1)
           / \
      (0) A   G (1)
             /
            D (0)
```

The numbers in the brackets are the balance factors.

Now, If I am to follow the book height of D is 1 and right subtree of G has height (-1) since its empty, so Balance factor of G should be = 1-(-1)=2!

Now why has it taken the height of D to be 0 here ?

PLEASE HELP.

Comment: You know, it might simply be that "height" is not rigorously defined (outside of an individual author's work or instructor's classroom, if that).

Comment: height can be defined either way. You just have to adjust the algorithms with `height` or `height-1`

Comment: But since I am preparing for an examination, what do i accept as the right interpretation, when I have to solve a question which requires height its really scary to be doubtful about such a basic thing.

Comment: In the U.S. the first floor is what the ground floor is in Europe.  In France that would be rez-de-chaussée :-)

Comment: accept the interpretation your course states

Comment: What about the height of a leaf node, I would take it to be 1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact definition of height doesn't matter if what you care about is balance factor. Recall that balance factor is

```
height(left) - height(right)
```

so if both are one larger or one smaller than in your favorite definition of height, the balance factor doesn't change, *as long as* you redefine the height of an empty tree accordingly.

Now the problems is that the "maximum number of nodes in a branch" definition is both recursive but doesn't specify a base case. But since the height of a single-element tree is one according to this definition, the obvious choice for the height of a zero-element tree is zero, and if you work out the formulas you'll find this works.

You can also arrive at the zero value by observing that the base case of the other definition is -1, and otherwise it always gives a value one less than the "max. nodes in a branch" definition.

Comment: So according to this definition I should take height for a zero element tree to be 0 instead of -1 which would be the case if I am using the other definition. Thanks a lot :-)